# Is there a way to prevent the same IF loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

Hey guys i am doing a check on my app version to clear the cache and to delete the local storage . But something is not right because i am in one loop and the app keeps refreshing . What am i doing wrong ? 
Basically i am creating an a `currentVersion` item into my `localStorage` and i am doing a request to check on if there is a new version . But my `currentVersion` keeps updating and the app is in refresh loop .

```
    export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
              currentVersion: '',
              versionFromRequest: ''
  }
}

   async componentDidMount() {

    axios.get(SERVER_URL + '/api/appVersion')

        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                versionFromRequest: response.data
            });
        })
         const branding = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('page'));

         localStorage.setItem('currentVersion', branding.version)

  this.setState({
    branding,
    pageReady: true,
    currentVersion: branding.version
});
...
render() {
    const { branding, versionFromRequest, currentVersion } = this.state;

 if(currentVersion !== versionFromRequest){
       caches.delete(arguments)
       localStorage.removeItem('access')
       window.location.reload()
     } else {
return(
...
)
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting `localStorage.setItem('page', ...)`

Comment: it is from the previous request it is the initial one that is performed on launch . It is not based in this component

Comment: So this doesn;t get updated hence will always remain stale. Isn't it?

Comment: normally yes this doesn't get updated into this component

Answer (score 0):

To me the problem seems to be this:

`const branding = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('page'));`

You're getting `currentBrandingVersion` on the basis of this `page` key on the localstorage.

This `page` key key never gets updated. Hence, the `currentVersion` derived from it, if doesn't match once, remains stale always and the page keeps loading. To fix this, you could do something like this:

```
if(currentVersion !== versionFromRequest){
       ...
window.location.reload();
     localStorage.setItem('page', ...); //Set the key so that the condition doesn't match the next time.
     } else {
    ...

}
```

Comment: Okey i understand , but why it is keeping me into the same loop . I am saying if the `currentVersion` is not equal to the `versionFromRequest` do something else continue with the rendering . But it keeps me only into this if statement

Comment: That's because, `currentVersion !== versionFromRequest` condition gets satisfied and inside this you've written `window.location.reload()` which refreshes the page. When the page refreshes, this condition gets satisfied again (remember you aren't updating `page` key in the `localStorage`) and again creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @PandaMastr Updated the answer. Check now.

Comment: but i cannot set this item to the local storage because it was called from my `App.js` the previous component with a request and it was looking something like this 
`localStorage.setItem('page', JSON.stringify(response.data.branding));`

Comment: So it seems like a design flaw. Do you get the problem? You're comparing previous version and new version, if both mismatch, you reload the page. But you're never updating the previous version with the latest one. So wouldn't the page keep reloading itself in an infinite loop. Even if you're setting it from `App.js`, that should work provided this components loads later once App component has done its part. Do you get the idea?